# ORACLE SQL: After Update SQL trigger is not working. The part between BEGIN and END does nothing

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_port_af_insert
AFTER UPDATE ON port
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO port_log_history VAlues ('SOME' ,'After_Insert_port')
END;
```

Comment: As written above it is invalid because it is missing a semi-colon `;` at the end of the `insert`.

Comment: I missed the semi colon here. But still the trigger does nothing when I make any updates to 'port'

Comment: Is the trigger enabled?  If you add a `dbms_output.put_line` call and do an insert with server output enabled, do you get the put_line message?

Comment: List explicitely all colums in the insert statement, just: `INSERT INTO port_log_history( colname1, colname2)  VAlues ('SOME' ,'After_Insert_port');`. If the table has more than 2 columns, then the trigger fails.

Comment: @Tony Andrews  The trigger is enabled. I cannot do 'Put_line' as I am not working on an actual 'database management system ' but on an web app that simulates the same.

Comment: @ krokodilko tried with column names still doesn't work. The table in question only has two columns

Comment: @prince what?? If you are not on an actual database then all bets are off!

Comment: @Tony Andrews  & @ krokodilko I really appreciate your responses. Thank You.

Comment: @Tony Andrews Come on man!! This a sort of a test in my workplace. It has to work. Or else they wouldn't ask me to create a trigger in the first place.

Comment: Well, you have asked a question about a trigger not working in Oracle, but you are running it on something that isn't Oracle, and you didn't mention that in the question.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if it turns out that the issue is in the web app - maybe the "trigger simulation" feature is switched off!

Comment: You have enough feedback here to confidently go to your supervisor and say: "look, I've tried this trigger but it doesn't work in the web app.  Why is that?"

Comment: @Tony Andrews  Alright then. Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: @prince why don't you use such like statement `insert into port_log_history( colname1, colname2) values ( :new.colname1 , :new.colname2);` and after all transaction, don't you have any _commit_ in your caller code?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your triggen using [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0012b/1) and **it worked**.
Note - `/` is usea in this fiddle as a query terminator:

```
CREATE TABLE port_log_history(col1 varchar2(10), col2 varchar2(20))
/

CREATE TABLE port(
  x int
)
/
INSERT INTO port VALUES (1)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_port_af_insert
AFTER UPDATE ON port
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO port_log_history(col1, col2) VAlues ('SOME' ,'After_Insert_port');
END;
/

UPDATE port SET x = 2
/
```

---

And a result is:

```
SELECT * FROM port_log_history;

| COL1 |              COL2 |
|------|-------------------|
| SOME | After_Insert_port |
```

Comment: I thank you for your help. I believe there is indeed some issue with the web app that I am using